# How do I get different AUTH headers for different collections in Postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I'm using PostMan to test my REST API.  Sometimes I want to test my Production environment, sometimes I want to test by Development environment.  Both are authorized by different OAUTH 2.0 authorities.  However, when I modify the Authorization settings for one collection, they show up in the other.  For example, here's the general idea of my test scenarios:

[image]

When I modify the settings for my Development Collection:

[image]

Then I open my Production Collection, I get this:

[image]

How do I un-cross the wires so I can access a different authority for my production tests and a different authority for my development tests?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want or are looking for are environments. When you run a collection you can choose which environment to use. Here's a link to the documentation:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments/

Comment: It doesn't really explain why two different collections share the same Authentication.  I agree Environments look like they might do the trick, but according to the document you referenced, collections scope higher than environments.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the issue, what is the difference in how you get the access token between your prod env and your dev env? Is it different URLs or client ids?

Comment: It is both.  For example, my production client ID is 547f9399-dac0-4e7f-b386-b848a6520a7e whereas my development authority is 5d918d59-7387-4494-8fe4-0f8b04a216c6.  Each of these authorities have different login ids, so by virtue of changing the Client ID, I change the set of authorized users.  Trouble is, if I change the Client Id in the Production collection, when I go to the Developer collection, I see the Production Client ID.  As nearly as I can tell, the two collections share the same OAuth parameters.

Comment: I would suggest to create a request that is going to run first in the collection (postman runs tests in order) which will get and set your access token. The request can be the same for both collections, the key is to use variables in your requests and properly store the different values for each of your environments (prod vs dev) in the postman environments.

Comment: Yeah, I tried putting variables in the AUTH token request form (e.g. {{ClientID}}) and the forms stopped working.  It's like they're trying to read the variables literally.

Comment: I dont think that variables in the form will work, what you can do however is fill out the OAuth form then there's a `Preview Request` button, save the request or send the request and capture it in the console then recreate it. At that point you should be able to replace URLs, client ids, etc.